# programming with NASM in Windows XP

Tags: windows, nasm, winmain

I have the following code which assembles and runs fine on Windows XP 32 bit, 2.09.08 NASM:

```
; how to compile: nasm -f elf test.asm
; how to link: ld -o test.exe test.o

section .data

section .text

;global _WinMain@16
;_WinMain@16:

;global _start
_start:
    mov ax,4           

    jmp $
```

According to many tutorials on NASM the asm file needs the following in it:

```
global _WinMain@16
_WinMain@16:
...
```

As you can see my asm file doesn't have that in it. (it's commented out, All it has is _start). So what is with all of these tutorials mentioning the need for the global _WinMain@16 stuff when my assembly program doesn't have that and works?

this is the command to assemble: nasm -f elf test.asm
this is the command to link: ld -o test.exe test.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several types of application on Windows with different entry points depending on which type they are. By link.exe option:

- `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` - requires `main` and linking with `msvcrXX.dll`. These applications run in console windows; if you aren't running an instance of cmd.exe, one will be opened.
- `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` - `WinMain` is the starting point. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Usually in C, these `#include <windows.h>` and are linked directly to `kernel32.dll`. These a gui apps and are almost definitely linked with `user32.dll` and possibly `advapi32.dll` as well.
- `/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE` - there are two types of application here; drivers and applications. Native NT apps run during windows startup and require `NtProcessSStartup` as an entry point. There is no libc in native applications. Drivers are different again.

A full list of supported windows subsystems by `link.exe` is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

`_start` is the symbol windows will actually start your code running at. Normally, `libc` or the like actually handles `_start` and does some initial setup, so your program doesn't actually quite start at `_main`. If you wanted to link with `libc` you would have problems, since you'd have conflicting symbols with the libc library. If however you never intend to call any functions that are part of the C or C++ standard libraries, you are ok using `_start`.

**Edit** yikes I've just noticed this:

```
; how to compile: nasm -f elf test.asm
; how to link: ld -o test.exe test.o
```

I assume you're not using the `-f elf` one. ELF (executable and linkable format) is the linux format for executables; Windows requires Portable Executable (PE) images. The nasm option is `-f win32`, or for dos `nasm -f coff`.

**Edit 2** just to check, I assembled the code and disassembled it again. I also used mingw. Anyway, I got:

```
SECTION .text   align=16 execute                        ; section number 1, code
Entry_point:; Function begin
; Note: Length-changing prefix causes delay on Intel processors
        mov     ax, 4                                   ; 00401000 _ 66: B8, 0004
?_001:  jmp     ?_001                                   ; 00401004 _ EB, FE
; Entry_point End of function
; Note: Length-changing prefix causes delay on Intel processors
        mov     ax, 4                                   ; 00401006 _ 66: B8, 0004
?_002:  jmp     ?_002                                   ; 0040100A _ EB, FE
```

The rest of the header appears to be a valid PE format executable with no Entry point specification. I believe therefore that the code is simply "falling through" to the first piece of assembly code to start. I wouldn't advise this behaviour, especially when linking multiple objects as I've no idea what would happen. Do use `-entry`.

Disassembling the elf object file I get this:

```
SECTION .data   align=4 noexecute                       ; section number 1, data
SECTION .text   align=16 execute                        ; section number 2, code
_start_here:; Local function
; Note: Length-changing prefix causes delay on Intel processors
        mov     ax, 4                                   ; 0000 _ 66: B8, 0004
?_001:  jmp     ?_001                                   ; 0004 _ EB, FE
_another_symbol:; Local function 
; Note: Length-changing prefix causes delay on Intel processors
        mov     ax, 4                                   ; 0006 _ 66: B8, 0004
?_002:  jmp     ?_002
```

In other words, there aren't any specific ELF-format headers in it. I believe you're getting lucky on this one; start importing or trying to link with other code modules and things will start to get more tricky.

For Windows / mingw, you want:

```
nasm -f win32 file.asm
```

for each file you want to assemble. Substitute `win32` for `win64` when needed. `ld` will do fine for linking.

Just a thought - I never explained the `@16` part. The functions are 16-byte aligned on Windows, whereas, as you can see, the data is only four-byte aligned. See [this explanation](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13265) for the why.

Comment: I not using link.exe to link my program. I'm using ld. I tested a new starting point: _startHerePlease: ... which also assembles and links and executes without problems. If I'm using bare bones assembly (without C, C++ or other libs) then I can make my starting symbol anything?

Comment: no i have been using that command to assemble it: nasm -f elf test.asm. Also have been using the linking command: ld -o test.exe test.o. It works fine for my windows box

Comment: @TheFuzz yes you can, with `ld --entry=_startHerePlease`.

Comment: @Ninefingers I don't specify the entry point when using ld and I don't have problems.

Comment: I should only use the -f win32 option when linking with Microsoft's linker correct?

Comment: @TheFuzz no. Use `-f win32` when on Windows. See my updated answer. Since nothing you're doing is causing entries in the elf format, I believe you're getting lucky, but you will run into trouble. `ld` can link `win32` files just fine.

Comment: -f win32 creates *.obj files while -f elf creates *.o files which MinGw normal creates for my C++ projects. so what is the problem with using .o files for my linking? mingw does it...

Comment: @TheFuzz object files (as in PE) aren't required to contain PE headers, just assembly. The problem comes if nasm -f elf ever decides to emit an elf header of some type that isn't applicable to windows applications.. It may never do this, but I'd rather say "use win32". I have absolutely no idea what ld would do; I expect it would complain about the object format. As to file extensions, obj is the MS convention, however, you're not obliged to use it, just use `-o myobjectname.o` ld will use either on windows, although nasm clearly defaults to the windows convention.